# Direct photo and name to Profile page

Tags: 8, theming, users

**Update#2**

Actual user name is `superuser` but with kint, its still reading the admin `id` and `displayname`. This also happens to the URL, its reading the admin's profile link `profile/1`

[image]

I tried to dig into `{{ content }}` but cannot find tag with value `superuser`.

---

**Update:**

I noticed that in my twig template, `{{ content.user_id }}` would link into user's profile page(`user/1`), so the main question I think is what is the correct profile id of user in twig. I tried using `content.profile_id` but doesn't work.

---

I have this simple site that a user can post a simple content in the site. I also have a custom Profile type enabled from Profile module. I noticed that when I click on the photo, it is directed to the profile page `profile/1`(which is my expected result) but when the author name is clicked, it is directed into the user's profile page `user/1`. How can I change the author's name link to be directed into profile page`profile/1`?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the example from [Twig Functions](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/functions-in-twig-templates):

> ```
> {# Link to user entity page. #}
> <a href="{{ path('entity.user.canonical', {'user': user.id}) }}">{{ 'View user profile'|t }}</a>
> ```

and modify the route to point the link to the profile page:

```
{# Link to user profile page. #}
<a href="{{ path('entity.profile.canonical', {'profile': user.id}) }}">{{ 'View user profile'|t }}</a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I use the below line and seems to be working. The link is directed into the profile's page however, the text displayed in the author's name is *View user profile'*.

Comment: You can replace the text from the example with `{{ user.displayname }}`

Comment: Encounter another issue when using `{{ user.displayname }}`, it display only the admin Name and not the others. I also tried your answer in https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/196637/70281 using `author_name` but giving me null value in `kint()`. Ill be sending the kint result in the issue above as reference.

Comment: The linked answer is for a node template and only there `author_name` is available.

Comment: so any idea how can to access profile name/id of the author who posted the content?

Comment: I think what happens here `'profile': user.id}`, is that its reading the `user.id` and since `user.id` has value of `1` that is assign into the admin, then would also create the admin profile link. Can we specify reading profile id, say `profile.id`?

Comment: Yes, then you are not in the user template, but in a different template, probably that of the profile and then try `profile.id`, this works for any entity. You can see which variables are available at the top of the twig file. BTW `user` is one of the few global variables available in all templates, but then refers not to the user entity, but to the current account. This is why you always get `1` if you try this as admin.

Comment: Right, `user.displayname` differs to the current account, not as the author of the post. This is the template I am using, of which photo is link to the profile URL, but `content.user_id` directs to the user's profile page https://github.com/goalgorilla/open_social/blob/8.x-2.x/themes/socialbase/templates/post/post.html.twig#L34

Comment: I found some workaround that shows the profile id to generate the URL using `{{ path('entity.profile.canonical', {'profile': author_picture['#cache'].keys.2}) }}` but I cant find how I can display the author's name.

Comment: If you can't find it in the existing variables, then define a new variable in a preprocess hook. You can use `author_picture` as example and do the same for `author_name`, then you already know how to get the author and only need to change the field.

Comment: this issue I am in seems to be more complicated than I thought. Not sure how to do that but ill try to find out. thanks for your help and suggestions.